# How to read subresource data in DirectX12?

Tags: directx-12

I have a DDS texture that I am creating using the `CreateDDSTextureFromMemory12` function from the `DDSTextureLoader` helper library from microsoft. The texture has 10 mipmaps. I am able to create the texture and use it without any problem.

What I would like to do is read the texture data for a specific mipmap at a given index.

Here I am trying to read the data at the subresource index 5:

```
DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromMemory12(
    g_device,
    g_cmd_list,
    &bytes.front(),
    file_size,
    texResource,
    tmpUploadHeap);

void* pData = nullptr;
texResource->ReadFromSubresource(pData, 64, 1, 5, nullptr);
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Resource1::ID3D12Resource::ReadFromSubresource: 
ReadFromSubresource can not be called on a resource associated with a heap that has the CPU page properties of D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_NOT_AVAILABLE. 
Heaps of the type D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT should be assumed to have these properties. 
[ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #895: READFROMSUBRESOURCE_INVALIDRESOURCE]
```

Comment: Are you using the DDSTextureLoader from the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12), from [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex), or perhaps some other variant of that code? My "original" versions have a ``LoadDDSTexture*`` function that gives you the 'raw' pixel data in CPU you could use. See [the wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/DDSTextureLoader#non-upload-versions)

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know. I actually managed to get the mipmap data by using CopyTextureRegion. I’ll still take a look at LoadDDSTexture. I’m using the version from DXT for DX12. I’ll post an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `LoadDDSTextureFromMemory` from the DirectXTK12 project on github. The 5th parameter returns all the subresources in a `std::vector`.